# How do I close ports in Linux for security reasons (KVM)?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I am going to set up a KVM virtualization server on CentOS. The host machine and several of the VMs will have a dedicated IP addresses.

I'm going to need to close off unused ports and probably provide port forwarding for some of the VMs.

I know I should [configure bridged networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/585020/how-do-i-configure-bridged-networking-for-vms) and then look into iptables. So far my default plan is to close off unused ports on host machine with iptables, and each VM will manage itself with iptables as well. When I'll need to set up port forwarding for VM's that don't have a dedicated IP, I'll have to expand the host machines' iptables rules.

Is this reasonable? Is there anything else I should know?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this seems reasonable. You should set the firewall policy to be deny and then only open the ports that you require.

Comment: So, when they say 'firewall' in Linux, that basically means iptables? I heard I have an option to use some filtering bridge too, but I'm not sure if that's a better idea.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov: In truth I think you're way out of your depth and you need some education in the tools you are attempting to use rather than a Q&A site. Without the education in the basics (which is not SF's mission) you (and your business) will end up in a bad place.